# Saving the title of a button so it can be accessed in another view (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, singleton, sigabrt

I'm trying to save the name of a button using a singleton so that the name can be accessed in another view to play a video with the same name.  However, I'm getting the error: SIGABRT.  I don't really see what's wrong with my code.  Any ideas?

```
#import "List.h"
#import "MyManager.h"
#import "Video.h"

@implementation ExerciseList

-(IBAction) goToVideo:(UIButton *) sender{
    MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
    sharedManager.vidName = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    Video *videoGo = [[Video alloc] initWithNibName: @"Video" bundle: nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: videoGo animated: YES];
    [videoGo release];
}
```

Here is my .h and .m for MyManager:

```
#import <foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyManager : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *workouts;
    NSString *vidName;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *workouts;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *vidName;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end

#import "MyManager.h"

static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;

@implementation MyManager
@synthesize workouts;
@synthesize vidName;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods
+ (id)sharedManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedMyManager == nil)
            sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedMyManager;
}
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        workouts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        vidName = [[NSString alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc{
    self.workouts = nil;
    self.vidName = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Show the declaration and implementation of the `vidName` property in `MyManager`, and the code that tries to access it. Right now you've shown that you're setting that property, but nothing about how the property is implemented, or what you do after you read from the property.

Comment: @KurtRevis  I just put up the .h and .m of MyManager

Comment: That looks OK. You're not showing where you read from the property, though.  Also: Where exactly is it crashing?

Comment: Considering [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855310/getting-sigabrt-signal-when-i-try-to-play-a-video-objective-c) which seems to be in related code -- do you think this question still stands? If the crash is in some other code, unrelated to the button title at all, then there is no point in anybody looking at this stuff.

Comment: @KurtRevis I just thought about that myself actually.  I'm going to see if the error lies elsewhere and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You should access the title of the button

sharedManger.vidName = [sender currentTitle];
However you are not using ARC so also check where your vidName property is `retain` or copy.
if it is not retain or copy then you can use this code also

```
if(sharedManger.vidname != nil){
    [sharedManger.vidName release]; 
    sharedManger.vidName = nil;

}
sharedManger.vidName = [[sender currentTitle] retain];
```