# Getting SIGABRT signal when I try to play a video (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, mpmovieplayercontroller, sigabrt

When I try to load a video, I'm getting a SIGABRT thrown.  Below is my code.  If anybody could let me know why I'm getting this error, that would be great.  The signal is being thrown for the line: theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

Two questions: what is wrong with my code?  and what does SIGABRT usually mean?

```
#import "Video.h"
#import "MyManager.h"
```

#import

```
@implementation Video

MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc{
     [theMovie release];
     [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
    NSString *tempName = sharedManager.vidName;
    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sharedManager.vidName ofType:@"mp4"];
    theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallBack:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    [theMovie.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
    [theMovie play];

    }

-(void)movieFinishedCallBack:(NSNotification *) aNotification{
    theMovie = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];
    [theMovie.view removeFromSuperview];
    [theMovie pause];
    [theMovie stop];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [theMovie pause]; // assume myMoviePlayer is an instance variable
    [theMovie stop];
    theMovie = nil;
    [theMovie release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [theMovie pause]; // assume myMoviePlayer is an instance variable
    [theMovie stop];
    theMovie = nil;
    [theMovie release];

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you know how to see the crash report? Checking there may be able to give you some clues. It could be caused by an uncaught exception

Comment: @tams I'm very new to iPhone development and this is my first project ever in Objective-c.  I don't know how to view the crash report.  How can I get to that?  Is that just what's in the output log?  In the log it says: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: ok, I think if you are new you can start by debugging your view did load method. Place a breakpoint at the start of the method and step through the code. Make sure that all of your variables are correct and that your strings are getting set correctly. Perhaps the problem lies there.

Answer (score 0):

I find that Sigabrt errors usually appear when you try to access an object that is not there or is a null reference. 
So maybe your problem is that the file does not exist or maybe you have lost a reference to your file or your videoplayer object somewhere.

Peter